# Checking the port number in windows using bat file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to check the two ports are running or not.In case if any of the port is running means have to check the next port number and write the unused port number in the file.

For ex:tomcat default port number is 8080 and oracle port number 1521.
Assume the inputs are 8080 and 1521.
In-case if the 8080 is running have to check 8081 and in-case if this port also running means have to check the unused port number.Assume got the unused port number is 8086.
And this port has to write in the file Tomcat_port=8086.

The same for checking oracle port number also.

I am new to scripting please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is in batch scritping, a command that allow you to determine if a port is already used or not.

```
    netstat -o -n -a | findstr (search criteria)
```

After that, an error "ERRORLEVEL" is raised, to tell you if your criteria was reached or not. 
ERRORLEVEL equals 0 if everything works fine and is greater than 0 if not.

Assuming that, find below a script that ask you a starting port, and automatically stop if there is an available port for you. It also write that port in a file named Availables.txt

```
     @echo off
     set /p port=Type the beginning port  
     set /a BPort=%port%


     setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
     echo Available ports >> Availables.txt 
     set /a Maxport = 65535 - BPort

     for /l %%X in (0,1,!Maxport!) do ( 
     set /a tempo=BPort+X
     echo Current port=!tempo!   
     netstat -o -n -a | findstr :!tempo! 
     if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0 (@echo "Port available") ELSE (@echo Port : !tempo! is   Available sir ! >> Availables.txt 
     goto eof) 
     set /a BPort=BPort+1 )

     echo There is any port available for you sir :(

     :eof
     echo Available port found 
     echo Finish processing
     pause
```

Tell me if it worked for you or for any question.

Answer (score 0):

This code defines a subroutine/function (`findFirstAvailablePort`) to do the work or searching for the first available TCP port from the starting indicated number. The value is returned in a variable (also passed on subroutine call).

This function is then called twice to retrieve the availables port starting from 8080 and 1521. Then the retrieved data is echoed to console.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    :: search for available ports
    call :findFirstAvailablePort 8080 tomcatPort
    call :findFirstAvailablePort 1521 oraclePort

    :: echo the retrieved data
    echo Tomcat_port=%tomcatPort%
    echo Oracle_port=%oraclePort%

    endlocal
    exit /B


:findFirstAvailablePort startingPort returnVariable
    setlocal enableextensions
    :: Generate a list of the open ports and save in temporary file
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.tmp"
    ((@for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('netstat -an -p tcp'
     ) do @for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=]" %%b in ("%%a"
     ) do @if "%%c"=="" (@echo(x%%b) else (@echo(%%c)
    )|@for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%d in ('more') do @echo($%%d$) > "%tempFile%"

    :: Test temporary file for next available port
    (break|@for /l %%p in (%~1 1 65535) do @(
        find "$%%p$" "%tempFile%" >nul || exit %%p
        if %%p==65535 exit 0
    ))
    set "port=%errorlevel%"

    :: clean and exit returning port
    endlocal & del /q "%tempFile%" 2>nul & set "%~2=%port%" & exit /b
```

The work in the function is divided in two parts.

The first part reads the output of the netstat command and splits the line to retrieve the list of open ports and generate a temporary file to analyze.

The second iterates checking the port numbers against the temporary file searching for the first port number that can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

OS: Windows 7 - 64 bit

This batch script finds an **UNUSED UNPRIVILEGED PORT** and uses it to open a local web application ([Portable R Shiny App](http://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/)) using portable google chrome web browser from a USB Flash drive. In the above weblink, the author's suggestion to create separate runShinyApp.R and run.bat was condensed to a single batch file as given below.

```
@echo off
    title My Shiny APP

    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    for /l %%X in (1025,1,65535) do (   
    netstat -o -n -a | findstr :%%X 
    if !ERRORLEVEL! neq 0 ( set avail_port=%%X
    goto eof) 
    )

    :eof
    SET ROPTS=--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole

    start "" ".\GoogleChromePortable\App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe" "http://localhost:!avail_port!/"

    R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe %ROPTS% -e "require(methods); shiny::runApp('./shiny', launch.browser = FALSE, port = !avail_port!)" 1> ShinyAppOut.log 2> ShinyAppMsg.log
```